# For odoo folks: what is the difference between developing with odoo on ubuntu desktop and ubuntu server?

Tags: odoo

What is the difference between developing with odoo on ubuntu desktop(Host + Guest) and ubuntu server (Host)?

What is the differance between odoo's instances in both systems?

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is not any difference, for both instances odoo package is same

Comment: thank you for you answer ^^ ! any source or documentation in this subject?

Comment: if you check odoo's [github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo) there you might find more information